# Is there a way to display my prime number list output in 2 columns?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am taking my first programming class and this is my first time posting. I have been able to find help on this site for previous projects when I got stuck, and I hope I am doing this right.

I have completed the program below to display only prime number between 0 and 100 for my intro to C++ class.

The only thing is it kinda bothers me that it is in a single column, I wanted to go the extra step and make it look all nice and display the numbers in a couple columns. I tried using "\t", but I can't get it to work right. Any ideas on what I might add to my code? 
   I think I could do it using an array but we have not covered it in class and I'm not supposed to use them yet.

the challenge was:

*"Use the isPrime function that you wrote in Programming Challenge 21 in a program that stores a list of all the prime numbers from 1 through 100 in a ﬁle."*

and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
static int num1=0;

cout<<"Listed below is all prime numbers from 1 through 100."<<endl<<endl<<endl;

do
{
    num1++;
    if (isPrime(num1))
    {
    cout<<num1<<endl;
    }
}
while (num1<100);

cout<<endl;

return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int num1)
{

bool primeNum=true;
for (int i=2;i<num1;i++)
{
    if (num1%i==0)
    {
        primeNum=false;
    }
}
return primeNum;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any input,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find cout.width()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
    static int num1 = 0;

    cout << "Listed below is all prime numbers from 1 through 100." << endl << endl << endl;

    int column = 0; // column variable
    int width = 10; // column width size

    do
    {
        num1++;
        if (isPrime(num1))
        {
            cout.width(width); // set column's width
            cout << num1;

            if (column == 1) { // if prime number is printed in column 2
                cout << endl; // add new line
                column = 0; // set column to first
            }
            else {
                column++; // increase column index
            }
        }

    } while (num1<100);

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int num1)
{
    // error: your isPrime returns true when num1 is 1 or 2. change it
    if (num1 == 1 || num1 == 2) return false;

    // your isPrime
    bool primeNum = true;
    for (int i = 2; i<num1; i++)
    {
        if (num1%i == 0)
        {
            primeNum = false;
        }
    }
    return primeNum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I didn't even notice 1 returning as true. But isn't 2 considered a prime though?

Comment: Oh that's my mistake. You have to change my code to like: if (num1 == 1) return false;

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the question asked for me to **STORE** the list to a file. So I rewrote and here is my new code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
int num=0;

cout<<"This Program will store a list of only the prime numbers "<<endl;
cout<<"between 0 and 100 to the text file \"PrimeNumberList\"."<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Find the list by using the file explorer to search for \"PrimeNumberList.txt\"."<<endl;


ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("PrimeNumberList.txt");

if (outFile.fail())
{
    cout<<"Error opening \"PrimeNumberList.txt\" for output."<<endl;
    return 1;
}

for (int i=1;i<100;i++)
{
    if(isPrime(i))
    {
        outFile<<i<<endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int num1)
{
if (num1==1)return false;
bool primeNum=true;
for (int i=2;i<num1;i++)
{
    if (num1%i==0)
    {
        primeNum=false;
    }
}
return primeNum;
}
```